# php remove duplicates from string, if duplicate length is > 4

Tags: php, regex, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates, if these duplicates got a length of more then 4 characters.

How can we achieve that? My current code also remove the duplicate - values.

CODE:

```
$seoproducttitle = 'HP Chromebook Chromebook 11 G5 EE - 11.6 inch - Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA#ABH';
$productnamestring = $seoproducttitle;
$findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/');
$replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1');
$productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);
echo implode(' ', array_unique(explode(' ', $productnamingseo)));
```

This outputs: HP Chromebook 11 G5 EE - 11.6" Intel® Celeron® 4LT18EA

It should output: HP Chromebook 11 G5 EE - 11.6" - Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA

Or: Apple MacBook Air MacBook Air - 13.3 inch - Intel Core i5-8e - MRE82N/A

Should be: Apple MacBook Air - 13.3 inch - Intel Core i5-8e - MRE82N/A

EXAMPLE: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5bcaaf47ca97d6dee359802f2d71c2d889c0d091

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Duplicate what? Can you provide some sample inputs/expected outputs?

Comment: @FrankerZ In this case the string got two times the value 'Chromebook'. I want to remove all duplicate values when the length of the duplicate is more than 4 characters. So in the string above it should only remove 1 'Chromebook'. But it should not remove the duplicate '-' signs.

Comment: Please edit your original question, with those examples/clarifications.

Comment: @FrankerZ I edit the question, see also the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Based on comments from OP, the required regex is

```
/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/
```

This looks for a group of 4 or more characters preceded by either a space or the start of the line and followed by a space, some number of other characters and then the group repeated again. The regex is replaced by `$1$2 $3` which effectively removes the duplicate string. A couple of examples:

```
$seoproducttitle = 'Apple MacBook Air MacBook Air - 13.3 inch - Intel Core i5-8e - MRE82N/A';
echo preg_replace('/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', "$1$2 $3", $seoproducttitle) . "\n";
$seoproducttitle = 'HP Chromebook 11 G5 EE Chromebook - 11.6 inch - Intel® Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA#ABH 4LT18EA#ABH';
echo preg_replace('/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', "$1$2 $3", $seoproducttitle) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Apple MacBook Air - 13.3 inch - Intel Core i5-8e - MRE82N/A Array
HP Chromebook 11 G5 EE - 11.6 inch - Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA#ABH
```

Updated [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/meu4l)

**Original Answer**

You could use this regex:

```
\b([^ ]{4,})( |$)(.*)\1
```

It looks for a group of 4 or more non-blank characters, followed by a space or end-of-string, followed by some number of other characters and then the first group repeated. The regex is replaced by `$1$3` which effectively removes the duplicate string. e.g.

```
$seoproducttitle = 'HP Chromebook 11 G5 EE Chromebook - 11.6 inch - Intel® Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA#ABH 4LT18EA#ABH';
echo preg_replace('/\b([^ ]{4,})( |$)(.*)\1/', "$1$3", $seoproducttitle);
```

Output:

```
HP Chromebook11 G5 EE - 11.6 inch - Intel® Celeron® - 4LT18EA#ABH
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AN9JP)

Comment: Thanks Nick! But I need to keep my current code also, so that it will keep replacing the other things. So I need to extend my current code. How to achieve that?

Comment: @HenkZ just add my search and replace strings to your `$findseo` and `$replaceseo` arrays e.g. `$findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/\b([^ ]{4,})( |$)(.*)\1/'); $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$3');`

Comment: Many thanks! Works almost perfect, but we also have this title: Apple MacBook Air MacBook Air - 13.3 inch - Intel Core i5-8e - MRE82N/A. In that case it should remove the second part of "MacBook Air". How to achieve that?

Comment: @HenkZ Are the duplicate *always* adjacent?

Comment: Yes they will be indeed adjacent.

Comment: @HenkZ I think I've come up with a solution which doesn't care if they are adjacent or not. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! How to include this one also inside the current code? By adding it into the $findseo?

Comment: @HenkZ Same as before `$findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/'); $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3');`

Comment: Hi Nick, I currently got only 1 problem left. The following title: Samsung LH55DBEPLGC - 55" - Full HD - LH55DBEPLGC. Will become: Samsung LH55DBEPLGC - 55" - Full HD -. In this case I also need to remove the last '-' sign. How can we achieve that?

Comment: @HenkZ Just need to add another set of values to the find and replace arrays: `$findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/'); $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Computers only do what we tell them, so you first need to explain the process to *yourself* in plain language. Then translate *that* to code. Then if you're having trouble doing *that* you've at least got a proper description of the problem to post on StackOverflow .

```
$words = explode(' ', $productnamingseo);
// start with an empty list of words we've seen
$output = [];
// for every word
foreach($words as $word) {
    // if it's longer than 4 chars and we've already seen it
    if( mb_strlen($word) >= 4 && in_array($word, $output) ) {
        // debug: show omitted words
        // $output[] = str_repeat('X', mb_strlen($word));
        // skip it
        continue;
    }
    // otherwise, add it to the list of words we've already seen
    $output[] = $word;
}

var_dump(
    $productnamingseo,
    implode(' ', $output)
);
```